# Why is my dropdown menu showing at the top?

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive website built with Bootstrap 4. I have a dropdown button that when clicked shows a dropdown menu.  When testing the dropdown in my phone (iPhone XR), the dropdown is showing at the top of the website, instead of right below the dropdown button as it should.

```css
/* DESKTOP */


/* Searchbar Container */

.searchbar-container {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

.square-btn-left,
.square-btn-right {
  background-color: #8ABE57;
  color: white;
  height: 45px;
  width: 50px
}

.searchbar-field {
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.category-dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0.35rem 1.5rem;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.category-dropdown-menu li a {
  color: #31353C;
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle square-btn-left" data-toggle="dropdown" id="serviceCategorySearchDropdown">
                            <i class="far fa-list-ul"></i>
                          </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu category-dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-shovel pr-3"></i>Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-utensils pr-3"></i>Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-ruler-triangle pr-3"></i>Item 3</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">
</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that when the button clicked `ul class="dropdown-menu category-dropdown-menu"` get a inline style. It gets also `show` class.

In order to override the style property you can:

```
.dropdown-menu.category-dropdown-menu.show { top: 3em!important; }
```

Here's a snippet:

EDIT per comments:

Since the inline style is generated from one of the plugins, you can remove it (and then it seems that you don't need the css at all). I put it on `setInterval` so it would fire last.

```js
$('#serviceCategorySearchDropdown').on('click', function () {
   setInterval(function(){ 
     $('.dropdown-menu.category-dropdown-menu.show').removeAttr('style');
   }, 50);  
})
```

```css
.dropdown-menu.category-dropdown-menu.show {
  /*top: 3em!important;*/
}






/* DESKTOP */


/* Searchbar Container */

.searchbar-container {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

.square-btn-left,
.square-btn-right {
  background-color: #8ABE57;
  color: white;
  height: 45px;
  width: 50px
}

.searchbar-field {
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.category-dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0.35rem 1.5rem;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.category-dropdown-menu li a {
  color: #31353C;
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle square-btn-left" data-toggle="dropdown"   id="serviceCategorySearchDropdown">
                            <i class="far fa-list-ul"></i>
                          </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu category-dropdown-menu" role="menu"data-placement="top-end">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-shovel pr-3"></i>Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-utensils pr-3"></i>Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-ruler-triangle pr-3"></i>Item 3</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">
</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

By the way `3em` calculated based on bootstrap `.btn` class sizes... change it as you like.

Comment: This works when previewing in chrome's development tool as mobile. However, when I try it on my phone, the menu is still at the top. Here's an image of my phone: https://imgur.com/9PVi2j5

Comment: @Paula - seems that the best approach would be to remove the inline style on button click. please check updated answer.